# 'No volume found' on Windows 7 VM (VHD), can I get anything back?

Tags: windows-7, windows

The worst possible situation...

Despite my vigilence doing backups, and trying to keep my PC secure, one of my VMs disk seems to be wiped out. Using the VHD tool from R1Soft (HyperV VHD Explorer), when I attach the VHD, it says no volumes found so it looks like something wiped out the VHD (which it still its original size).

It seems that something has sneaked through whatever security I have/had and has wreaked havoc.

Can I recover anything from this?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I recover anything from this?

Yes, everything from your latest backup.

If that's not an option, I suggest "acquiring" a copy of R-Studio's data recovery toolset (the network edition) and opening the VHD as an image file. I do not think R-Studio has native support for VHD but let it run a scan over the image and see what it can detect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using disk management in Windows 7 to mount the VHD? If it mounts, run a chkdsk on the mounted volume. (Make a backup of the VHD first)

How to mount using disk management
http://kb.acronis.com/content/3504

How to unmount when done
https://serverfault.com/questions/126377/how-to-unmount-a-vhd-in-windows-7-there-is-no-unmount-option

Some say they have retrieved data using VMWare Converter to convert the VM

https://serverfault.com/questions/34201/vhd-file-structure-repair-corrupted-vhd

http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/4_0

Also, you can try this software to mount the image
http://www.winimage.com/

.

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of the VHD, mount it with whatever you use to mount a VHD, then run [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) on it. It SHOULD, if there's any of the old FS structure left, detect and be able to recovery it.

I'd note tho whatever 'it' is may not be a virus, it could be anything from a bad shutdown, to the programme running the volume shutting down non cleanly.